# Created an S3 bucket, but not visible from the S3 console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am the root user and looks like I was able to create a bucket successfully but not able to see it on the console.

```
>>> s3.create_bucket(Bucket="test_bucket", CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'us-west-1'})
s3.Bucket(name='test_bucket')
>>> for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
...     print(bucket.name)
... 
test_bucket
```

I'm going through the documentation but the instruction here is so vague.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html I do not want to create two different users and just want to access my contents as a root user. Any help on this?

Comment: Are you running multiple AWS accounts, I mean accounts, not IAM users

Comment: No.. just one account. I also only have one access key id and secret key in my config

Comment: If you literally have a bucket called `test_bucket`, you should open a support ticket, that's an invalid name, and however it was created is a bug, and now doubt you're going to have issues interacting with it to any degree.

Comment: that's just me writing stuff anonymously.. it was more like `organization-name-lesson-number`

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you've set the region to either `Global` or `us-west-1` at the top-right of the window.

S3 Buckets are region-specific.

I also note that you've used an underscore in your bucket name. According to AWS's bucket naming conventions, this isn't allowed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html

`Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.), and hyphens (-)`

You may not have actually created the bucket!

Comment: I'm unable to toggle to `us-west-1` as it's grayed out but I am set to Global.

Comment: It's funny that aws sdk doesn't handle this error 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_bucket
Even funnier when OP could still create it and list using sdk

Comment: I changed to `some-actual-bucket` and then tried the same thing but when I try to create from the UI it says the bucket already exists! :( but still not seeing from the UI..

Comment: Buckets names are in a global namespace across all users. Just because a bucket exists, doesn't mean you can see it or modify it.